# What quantity of freezing water could generate 300,000 joules of mechanical energy from expansion - enough to boil an electric kettle?

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, pressure, water, ice

When water freezes, it expands with considerable force - enough to break glass and burst through copper water pipes.

If this material expansion was harnessed  - e.g. liquid water placed in a container that can withstand the pressure, and the expansion upon freezing used to pressurise air or some other gas - what volume of water would be needed to capture 300,000 joules - equivalent to a small kettle (2kWh rating boiling for 2.5 minutes) - worth of usable energy?

Comment: As a minimum effort, you could look up the values of the relevant quantities.

Comment: A kW is not a unit of *energy*.

Comment: @alephzero a kw is not a measure of energy a kwh is

Comment: Thankyou, I now understand the relationship between joules and kWh! I only studied physics up to GCSE level and that was some time ago so my understanding is a little hazy

Comment: I also changed the quantity of joules so it represented a common value, e.g. the energy required to boil an electric kettle

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following apparatus. A mass $m$ of pure water sits in a strong cylinder. We cool it down to $\text{O}^{\circ}C$ and then close it off. At that point and that temperature the headspace above the water is a volume $V$ of an ideal gas (air is close enough). Assume for simplicity's sake $V\gg m$:

[image: Ice cylinder]

The water will now freeze to ice at $\text{O}^{\circ}C$ and the gas will be slightly compressed, due to expansion of the water/ice.

The expansion of the water to ice can be found from the densities of water and ice at $\text{O}^{\circ}C$ (see Wikipedia) and I leave that to you. I'll call the expansion $\delta V$.

The work (this is actual energy i.e. $\mathrm{J}$) done on the gas is now:

$$W=\int_0^{\delta V}P\text{d}V=P\delta V$$

where $P$ is the pressure. Because $\delta V$ is small I've assumed here that $P\approx \text{constant}$ (e.g. atmospheric pressure).

Play with some numbers to get a feel for how much energy this expansion could deliver.

> What quantity of freezing water could generate 300,000 joules of
> mechanical energy - enough to boil an electric kettle?

As seen above the quantity of water isn't the only factor: the pressure at which the process takes place strongly influences how much work the freezing work will do.

Comment: Thanks Gert. The density of water is 0.999 g/cm3 at 0 degrees C, and ice is 0.917g/cm3 .... so is that an expansion of about 8% ? I honestly don't know how to use the formula you've provided

Comment: Yes, $1\text{cm}^3$ of water becomes $1.0895\text{cm}^3$ of ice. So if $m=1\text{g}$ then $\delta V=0.0895\text{cm}^3$.

Comment: So I guess if we say there is 1litre of water and 1litre of air at normal atmospheric pressure in the cylinder, then that air will be reduced in volume by 9%? If I knew how much energy it took to reduce 1litre of air by 9% then I guess I could start figuring it out...

Comment: If you know $\delta V$ (the expansion) and the pressure at which it takes place (assumed constant) then the work done by the freezing ice on the air would be $P\delta V$ where $P$ is the pressure.

Comment: I struggle to get my head around these equations, so I've attempted it another way. On the khan academy site I got some figures. Compressing 3 litres of air at 1 atm to 2.5 litres takes 56J. Thats a reduction of 16.666% for 3 litres of air. So to reduce 1 litre by 9% should represent about 10 joules.

Comment: So, 30,000 litres of water turning to ice should give enough compression to equal 300,000 joules, or one boiled kettle? Unless I have done the figures completely wrong, which is likely

Comment: $30000\text{ l}=30\text{ m}^3$, the expansion is $\delta V=2.7\text{ m}^3$. Multiply by the pressure $P\approx 100000\text{ Pa}$. So $W=2.7 \times 100000= 270000\text{ J}$

Comment: Of course here the pressure is really low, only $1\text{ bar}$. The work done on a burst pipe is at much higher pressure.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't that far off with those really roundabout calculations! This paper says it possible to extract 22 kJ of energy from 1 litre of water - is it totally wrong? https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329900438_Utilize_freezing_water_to_generate_energy&ved=2ahUKEwihjtXEmJzuAhVgQEEAHXhCDjcQFjACegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw39Ia4HPAggYfYo4XVj6lfw&cshid=1610654383179

Comment: Not wrong (I haven't read it). But $220\text{ MPa}=220\times 10^6\text{ Pa}$ or $\approx 2200$ times higher than our pressure! I doubt if significant amounts of energy can be produced that way, though...